# one LAMBDA function work with few methods

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API that has different methods - (GET, POST, DELETE) Is there a way to make one LAMBDA function work with all of these methods or does each method have its own LAMBDA function?
I mean I have parts in the code that each part is supposed to work in calling a different method.
and what if i have a few resources?

```
client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = client.Table('papi.table')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
//for GET METHOD
    tab=  table.scan()
    item = tab['Items']
    for id in item:
         print(id)

   // for POST
    response = table.put_item(
        Item={
            'id':"1"
            }
    )
    return response
```

and so..

Comment: You can proxy the `ANY` method requests to lambda and let it deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `httpMethod` parameter from the `event`, see [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) for the API gateway response to the Lambda.